# How to stop the grid from loading

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf, slickgrid

I have a ADF jsff page which contains a af:inlineFrame this frame invokes slickGrid, on save i validate the grid cells and error message is displayed by showing an alert message. Once i click on ok, i expect the grid to stay as it is but the grid gets loaded again. After displaying the alert message i have tried `window.frames[0].stop()`; but this didnt help

**JSFF:**

```
<af:inlineFrame id="slickFrame" 
                                source="/js/views/tarAutomation.html"                                
                                sizing="preferred" shortDesc="Slick Grid">
                    <af:serverListener type="onLoadEvt" method="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.initializeGrid}" />
                    <af:clientListener method="triggerOnLoad" type="inlineFrameLoad"/>
```

on click of Save

```
function save() {
// Parse through the dirtied cells
  for(d in dirtyCells)
   {   
     var dirtiedRow = dirtyCells[d].row;
     failures = //Gets the failure array
        if(failures.length>0){
          alert("Mandatory fields are not entered");                               
          grid.gotoCell(dirtyCells[d].row, dirtyCells[d].cell); 
        // This is to set the focus on the errored cells
          window.frames[0].stop();
       }
        else{
            //Continue with the save operation
        }
```

Please let me know how to stop the grid from getting loaded. I want the loading to stop so that the user selected options are seen as errored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to stop the grid from loading 
In the Jsff javascript function add event parameter 
At the end of this method add event.cancel() which would cancel the new events from being propagated 
Further details are here 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/web.1111/b31973/af_event.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's likely this is just an HTML issue, nothing to do with the grid. It's likely that the save button submits the form. You need to return `false` from the javascript event to prevent the default action (the submission).

Have a look here: [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

`<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();">`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateMyForm()
{
  if(check if your conditions are not satisfying)
  { 
    alert("validation failed false");
    returnToPreviousPage();
    return false;
  }

  alert("validations passed");
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried returning false and yet the triggerOnLoad method is getting called

Comment: It's likely to be something really simple. I notice you don't have a ```return``` in your code after the failure branch.